# Failed to start MySQL Community Server on Ubuntu 20

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm currently facing an issue with starting MySQL on my Ubuntu system. Upon attempting to restart the MySQL service, an error message stating 'Failed to start MySQL Community Server' appeared. As part of troubleshooting, I checked the available disk space on the system to ensure it wasn't a contributing factor to the error

[Free disk screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC8Mg.png)

Error log:
[Error log screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdd5A.png)

Comment: Use pastebin (or similar tools) and paste the last 100 lines of your mysql error log and share the link here.